# Store 2 dimentional array in strings xml

Tags: android, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I store this 2 Dimensional array in strings.xml?

```
private String[][] children = {
        { "Arnold", "Barry", "Chuck", "David" },
        { "Ace", "Bandit", "Cha-Cha", "Deuce" },
        { "Fluffy", "Snuggles" },
        { "Goldy", "Bubbles" }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your usage case would help answer the question, because depending on your situation, my suggestion would be to put the individual Strings in `strings.xml` and then use an `int[][]` inside your class pointing to the string resources:

```
private final int[][] children = {
    { R.string.arnold, R.string.barry, R.string.chuck, R.string.david },
    { R.string.ace, R.string.bandit /*etc*/ }
    // etc
    // ...
};
```

I know that doesn't directly answer your question as to how to do that in XML, but unless you provide a usage case that makes it clear that it's necessary to do that, there's no reason to do anything harder than what I've described.

Comment: Thank you. I am using the strings in an expandable list.